# What is the error in this Java code which is inside a JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

```
<%RemovableStorageEventListener listener = new RemovableStorageEventListener() { 
public void inserted(Storage storage) {%>
    enableButton();
<%} 
public void removed(Storage storage) {%>
    disableButton();
<%} }; 

BundleContext bc = AppManager.getInstance().getBundleContext();
StorageManager sm = StorageManager.getInstance(KSFUtility.getInstance().getApplicationContext(bc));
sm.addListener(listener);
%>
```

I get an error in the Start_jsp.java in

> out.write("\n\t\tenableButton();\n\t"); and 
>   out.write("\n\t\tdisableButton();\n\t");

```
RemovableStorageEventListener listener = new RemovableStorageEventListener() { 
public void inserted(Storage storage) {
  out.write("\n\t\tenableButton();\n\t");
} 
public void removed(Storage storage) {
  out.write("\n\t\tdisableButton();\n\t");
} }; 

BundleContext bc = AppManager.getInstance().getBundleContext();
StorageManager sm = StorageManager.getInstance(KSFUtility.getInstance().getApplicationContext(bc));
sm.addListener(listener);
```

Here is my javascript

```
function enableButton(){
document.getElementById('scan').disabled=false;
}

function disableButton(){
document.getElementById('scan').disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: What error in particular do you receive ?

Comment: cannot reffer to a non final variable out inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `out` variable `final`, because otherwise you will not be able to access it in `anonymous` classes (in your case, in the implementation of the `RemovableStorageEventListener`)

Java doesn't support true [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) (Java 8 is supposed to support them), even though using an anonymous class like you are using here (`new`RemovableStorageEventListener() { ... }`) looks like a kind of closure.

The variable `out` is local variable. The object that you create with the anonymous class might last until after the block that holds the `out` variable finishes. And when it finishes, the variable (`out`) will be cleaned up from the stack, so it won't exist anymore. In the mean time, the anonymous class object references that variable. Things would go horribly wrong if the anonymous class object tries to access the variable after it has been cleaned up.

By making it `final`, it is not really variable anymore, but a constant.

Comment: I can't make it final...because eclipse autogenerates the Start_jsp.java.